# Automatic E-mail not sending and E-mail system not fitting inside box

Tags: html, css

My automatic E-mail system isn't working and it won't fit into the box I made for it. The text-areas seem to be working, but when I press send, it doesn't automatically send the text. The only thing it does is open a mail application or chrome and then do absolutely nothing.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>contact</title>
<link href="contactcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<header>Bram Heesen</header>
<nav>
<ul>
<li>
<a class="huidig_rood" href="startpagina.html">HOME</a>
<a class="huidig_rood" href="paginainformatica.html">Pagina Informatica</a>
<a class="huidig_rood" href="paginamijzelf.html">Over Mij</a>
<a class="huidig_rood" href="paginakeuzeonderwerp.html">Pagina
Keuzeonderwerp</a>
<a class="huidig_blauw" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
<p>

Contact
U kunt hieronder een mailtje naar mij sturen, maar ik ben ook te bereiken op        
het nummer:  <span style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline;">06- 
14955860</span>
<form method="POST" action="mailto:bramheesen01@gmail.com">
Naam*:<br>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="name" SIZE="30"> <br>
E-mail*:<br>
<INPUT TYPE="text" EMAIL="E-mail" SIZE="40" <br>
<br><br>Wat voor soort bericht is het? <br>
<SELECT NAME="watfvoorsoortbericht" SIZE="1">
<OPTION SELECTED>Opmerking
<OPTION>Klacht
<OPTION>Vraag
<OPTION>Overig
</SELECT>
<br><TEXTAREA NAME="comment" ROWS=6 COLS=40>
</TEXTAREA>
<INPUT TYPE="submit">
<INPUT TYPE="reset">
</form>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
header {
color: GhostWhite;
text-align: center;
font-size: 60px;
margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
font-family: courier new;
}
body {background-image: url("images/wallpapermain.jpg");
color: white;
} 
p { border-width: 3px;
border-style: groove;
border-color: white;
background-color: black;
border-radius: 10px;
height: 1200px;
width: 1000px;
text-align: center;
font-family: "verdana";
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 50px;
margin-top: 0px;
}

img {border-radius:10px;
}
a:link.img { color:#007DC5;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
}
a:visited.img { color:#007DC5;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
} 
a:hover.img { color: red;
text-decoration:underline;
font-weight:bold;
}
/* menu */
a:link,a:visited {
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
background-color: black;
border: 2px #033 ridge;
border-radius: 10px; 
width: 140px;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover,a:active {
background-color: grey; 
color: white;
width: 140px;
}
nav {
height: 50px;
padding-top: 0px; 
}
ul {
margin:0;
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}
nav{
text-attachment: fixed;
}
a.huidig_blauw {
background-color: white;
color: black;
}
a.huidig_rood {
background-color: black;
color: white;
width: auto;
}
a.tweede_menu {
background-color: red;
color: blue;
width: auto;
}

<style type="text/css">
input[type=text] {width: 280px;
padding: 5px 3px;
margin: 8px 0;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
border-width: 3px;
border-style: groove;
border-color: black;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type=submit] {width: 150px;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 15px;
                background-color: blue;
                color: white;
                padding: 5px 3px;
                border: none;
                border-radius: 10px;
                border-width: 3px;
                border-style: groove;
                border-color: black;
                margin: 8px;
                font-family: arial;
}
input[type=reset] {width: 150px;
               text-align: center;
               font-size: 15px;
               background-color: blue;
               color: white;
               padding: 5px 3px;
               border: none;
               border-radius: 10px;
               border-width: 3px;
               border-style: groove;
               border-color: black;
               margin: 8px;
               font-family: arial;
}
textarea {padding: 5px 3px;
      margin: 8px 0px;
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border-width: 3px;
      border-style: groove;
      border-color: black;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: arial;
 }
div.contact {border-radius: 5px;
         background-color: blue;
         padding: 20px;
}
a.textcontact {text-attachment: fixed;
}
</style>
/* CSS Document */
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? `action="mailto:bramheesen01@gmail.com"`

Comment: You have a problem here: `<INPUT TYPE="text" EMAIL="E-mail" SIZE="40" <br>`. You did not close the input tag.

Comment: _"The only thing it does is open a mail application or chrome"_ - that's all that `mailto:` _does_. It does not automatically _send_ an email, it only opens the system's/browser's default email client (if that is even available, which is not a given). It might prefill a few fields with pre-set values (if done right [didn't check your code for that in detail, because there seems to be a general misunderstanding on your end what this can actually achieve, and what not], and supported by said client), but the user still needs to actively trigger sending the mail.

Comment: 1- Yes, the E-mailaddress is legit. 2- Ok I'll fix that right away. 3-Oh ok interesting, I followed a tutorial from another site which claimed it would automatically send the E-mail. I'll settle for this, though.

Comment: Also, does anyone know why it won't fit/appear in the box I made?